# NumericUpDown.value is not saved in the User Settings

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, application-settings, numericupdown

I have a NumericUpDown Control on a form. In the Application Settings / Properties Binding, for the value parameter, i can't select my USER setting called : Heures (Integer / User).

I tried to save the value by this way :

```
 Private Sub NumericUpDownHeures_Leave(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles NumericUpDownHeures.Leave
        My.Settings.Heures = NumericUpDownHeures.Value
        My.Settings.Save()
    End Sub
```

But it's not saved.
No problem for other settings (String / User). But i don't understand why the settings (Integer / User) are not saved.

Please help, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you are putting "NumericUpDown1.Value" you have to set the value at `My.Settings.Heures` to decimal.

In Form1_Load add:

```
NumericUpDownHeures.Value = My.Settings.Heures
```

and add to the event listener for your button or other widget:

```
My.Settings.Heures = NumericUpDownHeures.Value
```

Comment: Please translate your answer in English.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the issue is that the `Leave` event is not being fired as you expect it to be, especially if the user just clicks the up/down arrows. I suspect that it is only fired when the user actually clicks into the value area, then leaves. You could verify this by debugging to see if your code is ever hit or by showing a simple msgbox from that event.

I think that you will have better luck if you hook the `LostFocus` or `ValueChanged` event.

Comment: Hans give me the solution : it's just the fact that numericUpDown must be DECIMAL, not INTEGER !

Answer (score 0):

I want to add to this as well for anyone looking at this in the future.

Save your settings as shown already by putting
`My.Settings.Heures = NumericUpDownHeures.Value` into your ValueChanged event, and then doing reverse in the form load event.

The problem is, this value changed event fires before the form load when you first initialize, so it will keep defaulting to whatever value you have set in the designer because you're overwriting the setting value with the designer value.

To get around this, you need a private/public boolean at the top of your code that is only set to true once your form has loaded (set to true at the bottom of your form_load event), then you can add the condition to the ValueChanged event checking if the form is loaded yet or not. If it is, then change the setting value, if not, then don't.

An example:

```
Private IsFormLoaded As Boolean = False
    
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    NumericUpDown1.Value = My.Settings.SavedNumValue
    IsFormLoaded = True
End Sub

Private Sub NumericUpDown1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NumericUpDown1.ValueChanged
    If IsFormLoaded = False Then Exit Sub
    My.Settings.SavedNumValue = NumericUpDown1.Value
End Sub

OR

Private Sub NumericUpDown1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NumericUpDown1.ValueChanged
    If IsFormLoaded Then
        My.Settings.SavedNumValue = NumericUpDown1.Value
    End If
End Sub
```